# Блоки с изменяющейся высотой

Tags: css

В верстке по бокам декоративные элементы - синие полоски
[image]

При этом высота страницы не статична - в правом блоке Company News при нажатии на read more раскрывается-сворачивается полный текст новости http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index7/index.html. Не могу разобраться, как задать блоки, чтобы их высота так же увеличилась при удлинении страницы, то есть, чтобы поля у блока сверху и снизу всегда были одинаковыми.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте дополнительный блок-обертку с границами (border-image). При увеличении дочерних элементов, блок-родитель будет растягиваться по высоте.

Или я не правильно понял Ваш вопрос?

Comment: да, сделала через дополнительный блок-обертку, но боковые картинки задала не через border-image, так как это было бы не кроссбраузерно, а через блоки с абсолютным позиционированием.